# Better C# Syntax Coloring for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

Coming from Eclipse, I'm disappointed with the very limited syntax coloring capabilities offered for C# by Visual Studio (all versions, up to 2010).

In particular, I'm interesting in distinct coloring for methods / fields / locals / static stuff.

I'm aware Visual Assist can enhance the coloring, but I've failed to find any free alternative capable of doing that, so I'm turning to SO (I hope it's programming-related enough). Is there any free (or at least cheaper than Visual Assist) solution capable of enhancing the syntax coloring for C#?

Comment: What do you mean "up to 2010"? Even VS 2015 is the same piece of garbage.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I could understand from the rest of the responses that the answer is a resounding "no, there is no such extension available for free", so I ended up writing one on my own:

[image: better syntax coloring]

(light brown for methods, magenta for variables, otherwise their color would have been black)

It's a bit crude, but it works for me - and it was free :)

**EDIT:** Anyone interested in doing the same - using the "Editor Classification" template, bundled with the Visual Studio SDK, is a great starting point.

Comment: Nice... that's the spirit!!  +1

Comment: Any chance of releasing the thing as free/open source so the rest of us can enjoy it?

Comment: Not upvoting this, because it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 13):

It's not free, but ReSharper does this (and quite a lot more besides):

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Syntax_Highlighting

Comment: So it does, but looks like it's as expensive as Visual Assist, if not more :(

Comment: It's not expensive once you've found out how much it increases your productivity.

Comment: R# is invaluable. Once you have it, you will not be able to live without it. It makes coding so much more pleasurable. VisualAssist is more for C++ than anything else.

Comment: ReSharper basically makes Visual Studio comparable to Eclipse. You're going to keep finding missing features until you get it.

Answer (score 8):

Hmya, watch out: one IDE's flaw is another IDE's feature.  Visual Studio's syntax coloring is purely based on lexical analysis.  Fast, simple and always accurate, no matter how completely borked the code is while you are editing it.  To get the Eclipse-like coloring, the editor needs to be able to parse the code so it can classify identifiers.  That's a *much* harder problem.

More to the point, there are changes in VS2010 that emphasize doing things exactly the opposite way.  To get accurate syntax coloring your preferred way, you'd be likely to focus on getting the class "super-structure" done first.  Exactly the opposite of what VS2010 is doing.  It lets you skip the boring details and type code.  And offers refactorings that lets you automatically create the field/property/method declarations from that code.

Microsoft spends a lot of money researching the most effective use of their software.  You're liable to cut yourself off from the innovations they came up with if you try too hard getting things back the way you always did it before.

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't want to disagree with Microsoft's well paid researchers...  Why can't it attempt to do a semantic analysis then fall back on purely lexical if the parse fails?  Also, I don't see why better highlighting means refactoring is any more or less  useful.

Comment: I am aware of the method Visual Studio uses to colorize tokens - I have implemented a syntax colorer in Visual Studio myself, for a different language.
I agree, to some extend, that maybe I should accept the cons along with the pros of working differently than how I'm used to, but I don't think I'm asking for a lot - all I want is some syntax coloring and Visual Assist / Resharper seem to implement it just fine...

Comment: So, what did you implement?  Lexical coloring or parsing coloring?

Comment: Lexical only, and on an even simpler level than what C# does (I only inspected token types).

Comment: That's a creative explanation. But in fact, VS is already doing background compilation to give you error squiggles. You place too much faith in MS optimizing VS UX.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great free option, http://studiostyl.es/

Import the settings via Tools->Import/Export Settings

Answer (score 0):

[JetBrains ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) includes [enhanced syntax highlighting](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Syntax_Highlighting) but costs a bit more than Visual Assist. It is absolutely worth its price but not only for syntax highlighting.

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) offers [CodeRush and RefactorPro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/index.xml) probably including enhanced syntax highlighting, too, but I am not sure because I just tested it some time ago (at least it has a very [colorful overlay when it comes to refactoring](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dd218053.ExtractMethodToPerson3(en-us,MSDN.10).png)). There is a free edition - [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) - available.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears CodeRush Xpress does not have any enhancements to the syntax highlighting.